# Extract data from SQL database into excel report using PHPExcel

Tags: php, sql, excel, phpexcel

I need a PHP code solution to get selected SQL query data into excel workbook format. I've already implemented the code to generate excel workbook file. but the result shouldn't mach with the excel format that i need.

**Excel Report format I need**
 [image: excel report]

**My successful SQL query result**

[image: SQL result]

**MY PHP coding**

```
$get_mode = "SELECT
                sh_sso.showrooms.showroom_id,
                sh_sso.showrooms.showroom_name,
                Count(abans_crm.customers.purchase_type) AS mode_count,
                abans_crm.customers.purchase_date,
                abans_crm.pay_mode.pay_mode
                FROM
                        sh_sso.showrooms
                INNER JOIN abans_crm.customers ON sh_sso.showrooms.showroom_id = abans_crm.customers.location_id
                INNER JOIN abans_crm.pay_mode ON abans_crm.customers.purchase_type = abans_crm.pay_mode.mode_id
                WHERE DATE(abans_crm.customers.purchase_date) >= '$fromDate' AND DATE(abans_crm.customers.purchase_date) <= '$toDate'
                GROUP BY
                abans_crm.pay_mode.pay_mode,
                sh_sso.showrooms.showroom_name";

    $result = mysql_query($get_mode) or die(mysql_error());;

    $row = 6; 
    while($row_mode = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    

              $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$row, $row_mode['showroom_name']);   

              if($row_mode['pay_mode'] == 'Cash'){
                    if($row_mode['mode_count'] > 1){
                     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$row,$row_mode['mode_count']);
                    }
                    elseif($row_mode['mode_count'] == 1){
                      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$row,'1');   
                    }
                    else {
                      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$row,'0');   
                    }
              }
              if($row_mode['pay_mode'] == 'Credit Card'){
                    if($row_mode['mode_count'] > 1){
                     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C'.$row,$row_mode['mode_count']);
                    }
                    elseif($row_mode['mode_count'] == 1){
                      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C'.$row,'1');   
                    }
                    else {
                      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C'.$row,'0');   
                    } 
              }
              if($row_mode['pay_mode'] == 'Hire Purchase'){
                if($row_mode['mode_count'] > 1){
                     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D'.$row,$row_mode['mode_count']);
                    }
                    elseif($row_mode['mode_count'] == 1){
                      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D'.$row,'1');   
                    }
                    else {
                      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D'.$row,'0');   
                }  
              }
              if($row_mode['pay_mode'] == 'Lease'){
                if($row_mode['mode_count'] > 1){
                     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E'.$row,$row_mode['mode_count']);
                    }
                    elseif($row_mode['mode_count'] == 1){
                      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E'.$row,'1');   
                    }
                    else {
                      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E'.$row,'0');   
                } 
              }
              ++$row;
            }
   //}
//genarate report data
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test-report 2016-04-3.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

**AS AN EXAMPLE**
  Highlighted records data should be come into single row and the total of it. In this case TOTAL should be 37

Comment: How can i insert showroom_id equal values into one array ?